# ASP.Net MVC - updating areas of page based on drop down lists

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a product page which has 3 x drop down lists that allow the visitor to select product attributes - for example for a pair of trousers this could be colour / waist size / leg length.

Currently I have the drop downs hooked up as cascading by the use of jQuery and jSon - so each selection populates the next drop down list down the hierarchy by calling a JsonResult action via some jQuery within the page.

When all selections are made, and thus a visitor has decided upon a product variant, I need to update my page contents - elements such as price / image / stock availability / long description and a table of specifications can all be product variant specific. These page elements that need to change are distributed throughout the markup rather than being all in one block just to complicate matters a little.

Currently my page (view) just has all these elements within the main view itself - what is the best way to achieve changing the page to reflect the visitors choice?

This was a webforms app where I made use of several UpdatePanels to achieve the same thing, but as a relative MVC newbie I'm not sure of the approach to tackle this kind of problem?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you done so far i.e. could you provide some code snippets?

Comment: I wasn't sure what to add - code for drop downs or jQuery / Json I have for populating them? I don't really have anything yet for fetching the product variant details back to the page - well I have my DAL code that grabs it but nothing for bringing it back yet as was stumped with how to go about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have 3 major options:

1. Display prerendered view with all the data -  On a selection of third dropdown send an ajax request to server which should return a partial view. This view is going to be rendered with the model that corresponds to user selection. Once you get it you can simply inject it inside the DOM: `$('#itemDetails').html(yourRenderedViewHTML)` I am not familiar with WebForms but I think this is similar to UpdatePanels technique that you used.
2. Get raw data from server and bind it to some template - On a selection of third dropdown send an ajax request to server which should return a json result that will with all the requested data. Once this json arrives to the client you need to perform some kind of model binding. You can either do it manually (for each one of the elements you will have something like `$('#priceDisplayElement').text(model.Price)`)`. Or you can use some client side framework (for example [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/)) that could make this task much easier.
3. There is another option of doing a full postback to the server (instead of ajax call) which will re-render all the page. The server side code for this could look like:

   ```
   public class ItemModel
   {
      public int ItemId{get;set;}
      public string Description {get;set;}
      //all other props come here
   }

   public class GetItemDetailsViewModel
   {
      public ItemModel Item{get;set;}
      public int SelectedItemId {get;set;}
      //other properties for cascading dropdowns   
   }


   public ActionResult GetItemDetails(int? itemId)
   {

      var model = new GetItemDetailsViewModel();
      if(itemId.HasValue)
      {
          model.Item = //get item details from DB
      }
      return View(model);
   }
   ```

Inside your view you can check whether Item property is not null and to render all the data correspondingly. If the Item property is null you simply display dropdowns.

Comment: I was looking at first option I guess, but with the areas of the page that I want to update spread throughout the DOM/markup I figured I'd need multiple partial views? Wasn't sure if I could effect a refresh of multiple areas / partial views. Is what you are suggesting effectively going to mean rendering most of the page again - not that it's actually an issue, although I guess my drop downs are int he middle of it all!

Comment: For effectively using first option you will have to reorganize the page so you will have to replace only one partial view. The easiest fix wild be the third option with rerendering all page

Comment: I think I will look at Knockout.js actually - this may be easier / smoother - just had a go of some tutorials on their site and it looks promising